# How to handle Connect/ Authentication errors when using imap-idle-channel-adapter

Tags: spring-integration

I am able to handle and report connection/ authentication related errors for imap and pop adapter by using error-channel on the poller.

I have one for imap-idle too but its not getting these error on that channel but a warning in the logs only.

what is the way out to handle and report similar errors for email idle adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you mean this peace of code:

```
catch (Exception e) { //run again after a delay
        logger.warn("Failed to execute IDLE task. Will attempt to resubmit in " + ImapIdleChannelAdapter.this.reconnectDelay + " milliseconds.", e);
        ImapIdleChannelAdapter.this.receivingTaskTrigger.delayNextExecution();
        ImapIdleChannelAdapter.this.publishException(e);
        }
```

And you see that `WARN` in your logs.

Pay attention, please, to the latest line about `publishException()`. It is this code:

```
private void publishException(Exception e) {
    if (this.applicationEventPublisher != null) {
        this.applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(new ImapIdleExceptionEvent(e));
    }
```

So, what you need is to add an `EventListener` for that `ImapIdleExceptionEvent`. For example you can use [ApplicationEventListeningMessageProducer](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/applicationevent.html#appevent-inbound).

Comment: thanks, I will give it a try. How can I add custom header like 'adapter.id' I've one in for imap & pop where I'm passing adapter id through header enricher for the error-channel to know which adapter had the issue as system can have multiple imap and/or pop adapters and I've used parent/child contexts to control them.

Comment: The event does this `super(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.this, e);`. So, on the listener side you can track `getComponentName()` for distinguishing logic.

Comment: On (NamedCompnent) event.getSource()

Comment: thanks, I've not tried it yet but if there are two imap idle adapter instances and one is failing, would I know which one, so that I can call a stop on that and then remove the relevant child ConfigurableApplicationContext (ClassPathXmlApplicationContext) which gets attached to the parent spring context.

Comment: `(ImapIdleChannelAdapter) event.getSource()` from that `ImapIdleExceptionEvent` is an answer to you.

Comment: Thanks, it worked though I've to make few other changes to store the context id(s) to distinguish between two imap idle adapters as I could reply on applicationcontextid returned by ImapIdleChannelAdpater.